# Replace numbers in email body

Tags: vba, email, outlook

i have some numbers with point after them in emails. The problem is that they are descending in the email:  6. 5. 4. 3. 2. 1.    - first after hello is  6. 5. 4. 3. 2. 1.  But not always, sometimes are just 3 or 4 or 2 of them:   2. 1.   or   4. 3. 2. 1.     Is there a way to order them ascending after hello:   1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6.  via vba ? The text is plain text numbers and are only 6 numbers with point after them in the email. The numbers are not auto generated.

ex:

```
Hello, 

6. some thing to be done
5. some thing to be done
4. some thing to be done
3. some thing to be done
2. some thing to be done
1. some thing to be done

Have a nice day.
```

or

```
Hello, 

4. some thing to be done
3. some thing to be done
2. some thing to be done
1. some thing to be done

Have a nice day.
```

The auto paragraph is not working :

```
   * Hello, 
   * 
    4. some thing to be done
    3. some thing to be done
    2. some thing to be done
    1. some thing to be done
   * 
   * Have a nice day.
```

i have tried this but it doesn't work.

```
With objItem.Content.Find
    .Text = "6."
    .Forward = True
    .Execute

    If .Found = True Then
    objItem.HTMLBody = Replace(objItem.HTMLBody, "6.", "1.")
    objItem.HTMLBody = Replace(objItem.HTMLBody, "5.", "2.")
    objItem.HTMLBody = Replace(objItem.HTMLBody, "4.", "3.")
    objItem.HTMLBody = Replace(objItem.HTMLBody, "3.", "4.")
    objItem.HTMLBody = Replace(objItem.HTMLBody, "2.", "5.")
    objItem.HTMLBody = Replace(objItem.HTMLBody, "1.", "6.")

    Else

    With objItem.Content.Find
    .Text = "5."
    .Forward = True
    .Execute

    If .Found = True Then
    objItem.HTMLBody = Replace(objItem.HTMLBody, "5.", "1.")
    objItem.HTMLBody = Replace(objItem.HTMLBody, "4.", "2.")
    objItem.HTMLBody = Replace(objItem.HTMLBody, "2.", "4.")
    objItem.HTMLBody = Replace(objItem.HTMLBody, "1.", "5.")

    'Else...

    End With

End With
```

Comment: Have you tried the A->Z tool in Format Text, Paragraph?

Comment: hi, it doesn't put the paragraph where it should that is why i want to make it with vba.

Comment: Then you need to click the [edit] link below the question and add more details: describe what you mean by "doesn't put the paragraph where it should". You also need to specify whether these are "plain text" numbers or autonumbering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request is very vage. This is due to the fact that you want to parse a string which you haven't properly "defined". The missing pieces are:

(1) What makes a line a line in your string? Are they separated with a line break such as `vbCrLf` or are you using `Chr(10)` or anything else instead? Can it be all of them interchangeably?

(2) How do you want to tell VBA that a list starts and that a list ends? Is it that there is a number as the first character in a line? What if a line starts with a number due to other reasons or if someone put a space before that number such as `2. some thing to be done`. Then the first character would be a space and not a number. Especially, if your list surpasses 10 items it might be that the first 9 number will be written as `1.` (with a leading space).

(3) Once the list is completed no more list items should be generated and the list should be marked "closed". How do you define this? Is it that there were lines starting with a number before and that the next line does not start with a number anymore? But that would also mean that nobody can use a `Return` within any of the line items (because the description of what should be done is getting too long).

Since none of the above is included in your question, a reader might come to the conclusion that you haven't really fully understood the problem yet. I guess that explains also the comment by @CindyMeister.

Still, I had a little bit of a spare time and gave it some thought and came up with the following small sub:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub HTML_List()

Dim lngRow As Long
Dim lngChar As Long
Dim strTmp() As String
Dim strHTMLbody As String
Dim bolListStart As Boolean

strHTMLbody = "Hello,  " & vbCrLf
strHTMLbody = strHTMLbody & " " & vbCrLf
strHTMLbody = strHTMLbody & "6. some thing to be done " & vbCrLf
strHTMLbody = strHTMLbody & "5. some thing to be done " & vbCrLf
strHTMLbody = strHTMLbody & "4. some thing to be done " & vbCrLf
strHTMLbody = strHTMLbody & "3. some thing to be done " & vbCrLf
strHTMLbody = strHTMLbody & "2. some thing to be done " & vbCrLf
strHTMLbody = strHTMLbody & "1. some thing to be done " & vbCrLf
strHTMLbody = strHTMLbody & " " & vbCrLf
strHTMLbody = strHTMLbody & "Have a nice day. "

strTmp() = Split(strHTMLbody, vbCrLf)

For lngRow = LBound(strTmp) To UBound(strTmp)
    strTmp(lngRow) = Trim(strTmp(lngRow))
    If strTmp(lngRow) <> vbNullString Then
        Select Case Asc(strTmp(lngRow))
        Case 48 To 57
            strTmp(lngRow) = Mid(strTmp(lngRow), InStr(1, strTmp(lngRow), ".", vbTextCompare) + 1)
            strTmp(lngRow) = "<li>" & strTmp(lngRow) & "</li>"
            If bolListStart = False Then
                strTmp(lngRow) = "<ol>" & strTmp(lngRow)
                bolListStart = True
            End If
        Case Else
            If bolListStart = True Then
                bolListStart = False
                strTmp(lngRow - 1) = strTmp(lngRow - 1) & "</ol>"
            End If
        End Select
    End If
Next lngRow

strHTMLbody = ""
For lngRow = LBound(strTmp) To UBound(strTmp)
    strHTMLbody = strHTMLbody & strTmp(lngRow) & vbCrLf
Next lngRow

Debug.Print strHTMLbody

End Sub
```

So, the basic steps behind the sub are the following:

1. Split the initial string by `vbCrLf` (hopefully that makes a line a line).
2. Check if the first character in that line is a number.
3. With the first occurence of the above a list will be started. In HTML a list is started with `<ol>`.
4. Remove the number from that line and rather tell HTML that this is a list item. That's tagged with a `<li>` at the start of a list item and a `</li>` at the end of that line item.
5. Once, a line does not start anymore with a number, the list is closed in HTML with `</ol>`.
6. Bring all the lines together again into one HTML string.

If you use then this string in an Outlook email as `.HTMLbody` then HTML will automatically format your list and number the line items accordingly.

As a result of the above code you will get the following in return:

```html
Hello,

<ol><li> some thing to be done</li>
<li> some thing to be done</li>
<li> some thing to be done</li>
<li> some thing to be done</li>
<li> some thing to be done</li>
<li> some thing to be done</li>
</ol>
Have a nice day.
```

I hope that helps. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you, it does the job.