# Excel to WiKi macro

Tags: excel, wiki, vba

I need one macro for converting Excel spreadsheet to wiki format and post the same in wiki.

Sample data

```
Column-1    Column-2    Column-3
A           Val1          Val1
B           Val2          Val2
C           Val3          Val3
```

Lets say that we want to post the converted table to dummy := https://wiki.com/w/Qc/MyPage

Comment: What have you tried so far? What have you researched for this? People are much more likely to help you out if they can see that you have had a go at this yourself. This is not a free coding service I'm afraid.

Comment: The link is not working, hence I cannot see what you are aiming for. Anyway, it would be best to include all required information in this post and not link to other sites. Still, it seems to me that you are aiming for a `HTML` formatted table. So, basically you want to create `HTML` code with your table data. Is that correct? If so, the following solution I posted some time ago might give you a good starting point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36591427/replace-numbers-in-email-body/36814534#36814534

Comment: @Ralph its a dummy link, it won't work

Comment: @Glitch_Doctor so far i was using excel formulas to convert the values into wiki format(for each cell values).

Answer (score 0):

i Managed to develop the below code which **almost** makes a WikiSyntax.

Select the cell range to convert and run the macro.

```
Sub SelectionToWiki()
PadConst = "cellpadding=""1"" cellspacing=""1"" border=""1"" style=""width: 100%;"""
result = ""
result = result & " "

For i = 1 To Selection.Rows.Count
    For j = 1 To Selection.Columns.Count
        Dim cell As Range
        Set cell = Selection.Cells(i, j)
        cellStr = cell.Value
        result = result & Chr(13) & "| " & cellStr
    Next
    result = result & Chr(13) & "|-" & Chr(13)
Next

result = "{| " & PadConst & result & "|}"
Dim MyDataObj As New DataObject
MyDataObj.SetText result
MyDataObj.PutInClipboard

MsgBox "Wiki table copied to clipboard: " & Chr(13) & Chr(13) & result
```

End Sub

Enhancements will be much appreciated.